# How to fix the column size of a table even with 2 mixed header (with and without colspan)

Tags: html

first of all i'm sorry for my english.

I've a question about HTML and tables:
I'm trying to create a Table in HTML with two rows in header with different sizes and colspan, for example:

```
-------------------------
|        Hi There       |
-------------------------
|   a   |   b   | c | d |
-------------------------
```

A & B columns have automatic width and, C & D have a fixed width. My problem is that when i add the "Hi There" header then C and D colums changes to automatic width.
How i can fix that?

Here's a sample code and some screenshots:

```
<html>
<header>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Página de Prueba</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.body {
            width:          210mm;
            /* height:      297mm;
            border: 5px     solid red;*/
            margin-left:    auto ;
            margin-right:   auto ;
        }

        table {
            table-layout:   fixed;
            width:          100%;
            /* height:      100%;*/
            border:         3px solid black;
            border-spacing: 0px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        thead {
            display:        table-header-group;
        }

        th {
            background:     blue;
            border-bottom:  3px solid black;
            font-family:    "Verdana";
            font-size:      11px;
            color:          white;
            font-weight:    bold;
            padding-top:    5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }


        td.border, th.border {
            border-right:   1px dotted black;
        }

        td.fijo, th.fijo {
            width:          82px;
        }

        td {
            vertical-align: center;
            text-align:     center;
            font-family:    "Verdana";
            font-size:      10px;
            padding:        2px;
            white-space:    -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
            white-space:    -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
            white-space:    -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
            white-space:    pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
            /*word-wrap:    break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
            /*word-break:   break-all;*/
            white-space:    normal;
            border-bottom:  1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</header>

<body>
    <div class="body">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr><th colspan="6">Facturación por cliente y contrato</th></tr>
                <tr><th class="border">Cliente</th><th class="border">Contrato</th><th class="border fijo">Presupuesto</th><th class="border fijo">Pres. Mes</th><th class="border fijo">Pagado</th><th class="fijo">Desviación</th></tr>
            </thead>
                -----------Bla Bla Bla table-----------
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i comment the first header then works fine:
[image: Without Header]

But if i use the spanned header then it don't cares about column sizes.
[image: With Header]

How i can fix this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the "table-layout: fixed" and I think you are good to go:

```
    table {
        width:          100%;
        /* height:      100%;*/
        border:         3px solid black;
        border-spacing: 0px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
```

Fidlle: http://jsfiddle.net/eATYA/

Comment: Just working!! thanks!!. I really don't remember why i've used "fixed" in table, I think was because table fell outside the div, but now works :)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the column widths in the html seems to do the trick:

```
<col >
<col >
<col width="87">
<col width="87">
<col width="87">
<col width="87">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/John_C/8CkNk/

Answer (score -1):

The first one is a table header (th). The second one is a table row (tr) with table cells inside (td). Here is the correct HTML for what you're expecting.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th colspan="6" style="text-align:center">My awesome table</th>
    <tr>
      <td>Col #1</td>
      <td>Col #2</td>
      <td>Col #3</td>
      <td>Col #4</td>
      <td>Col #5</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data #1</td>
      <td>Data #2</td>
      <td>Data #3</td>
      <td>Data #4</td>
      <td>Data #5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Saludos!